# Does rsync delete files, folders at destination by default?

Tags: macos, bash, unix, rsync

### Files

Suppose that `/foo/src` contains only `A.c` and that `/foo/dest` contains both `A.c` and `B.c`. And suppose I run the following command:

```
rsync /foo/src/ /foo/dest
```

Will `rsync` erase `B.c`?

### Folders

Now suppose that `/foo/src` contains the directory `A` with some files inside it and that `/foo/dest` contains both directories `A` and `B`, each with some files inside of them. And suppose I run the following command (the -a option includes -r, recursive):

```
rsync -a /foo/src/ /foo/dest
```

Will `rsync` erase `B` and its contents?

Comment: You need the `--delete` switch.

Comment: Indeed, maybe you explicitly _don't_ need the `--delete` switch - it depends what result the user wants; see answers below.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

By default, rsync does not delete files but that depends on the commands options you specify. You can use any the following if you WANT to delete files:

- −−del (alias for −−delete−during)
- −−delete (deletes extraneous files from dest dirs)
- −−delete−before (receiver deletes before xfer [default])
- −−delete−during (receiver deletes during xfer, not before)
- −−delete−after (receiver deletes after xfer, not before)
- −−delete−excluded (also delete excluded files from dest dirs)
- −−max−delete=NUM (don’t delete more than NUM files)

Since you specifically called out the **-a** option, here's what the man page says

> ***−a, −−archive***
>   >
>
> > This is equivalent to **−rlptgoD**. It is a quick way of saying you want recursion and want to preserve almost everything (with −H being a notable omission). The only exception to the above equivalence is when **−−files−from** is specified, in which case −r is not implied.
> >
> > Note that **−a does not preserve hardlinks**, because finding multiply-linked files is expensive. You must separately specify **−H**.

So it seems the answer to your question is NO, it won't be deleted given your examples.
HTH

Comment: While this is an excellent answer, I don't think you should use the word "xfer" because, well, it's not a word. Let's make explanations easy for everyone to understand, including speakers whose native language is not English. (For anyone wondering, 'xfer' = 'transfer')